# how to make a new line in react intl?

Tags: javascript, react-native, internationalization

I have a question - how to make a new line in react intl? I put my translations in file like:

```js
[LOCALES.ENGLISH]: {
        'hello': 'Hello',
        }
```

and call them using . How to make a 2+ lines message??

Answer (score 25):

[Use an argument](https://formatjs.io/docs/core-concepts/icu-syntax#simple-argument) to add a `<br/>` tag:

```
const messages = {
  MESSAGE: {
    id: "message",
    defaultMessage: "<p>Message with {br} linebreaks</p>"
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={messages}>
      <div className="App">
        <FormattedMessage
          {...messages.MESSAGE}
          values={{
            p: (...chunks) => <p>{chunks}</p>,
            br: <br />
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}
```

Full sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/formattedmessage-key-error-6kx6c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you. Is there any option to globally config this ( Maybe in provider ) instead of doing it in every FormatMessage tag ?

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone is still looking for a fix.

you could use `\n` and use `white-space: pre-line` styles.

```
{'hello': 'Hello \n World'}

<p style="white-space: pre-line;"><FormattedMessage id="hello"/></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use message with variable and send `<br/>` as value of variable like fallowing :

```
    <FormattedMessage {...strings.headTitle} values={{br: <br/>}} />
```

strings :

```
export default defineMessages({
  headTitle: {
    id: 'test',
    defaultMessage: 'test {br} next line',
  } })
```

Answer (score -1):

Import ReactHtmlparser from 'react-html-parser';

In class construtor below super () add
This.formatMessage = props.intl.formatMessage

And use in your jsx

{ReactHtmlparser (this.formatMessage ({id : "your id"}) )}

export default injectIntl(MyClass);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).